Alignment issue with MathML long division problem in InDesign
I am attempting to render this long division problem from the MathML presentation markup documentation:
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" mathsize="10pt" mathcolor="#000000">
  <mlongdiv longdivstyle="lefttop">
    <mn> 3 </mn>
    <mn> 435.3</mn>
    <mn> 1306</mn>
    <msgroup position="2" shift="-1">
      <msgroup>
        <mn> 12</mn>
        <msline length="2"/>
      </msgroup>
      <msgroup>
        <mn> 10</mn>
        <mn> 9</mn>
        <msline length="2"/>
      </msgroup>
      <msgroup>
        <mn> 16</mn>
        <mn> 15</mn>
        <msline length="2"/>
        <mn> 1.0</mn>          <!-- aligns on '.', not the right edge ('0') -->
      </msgroup>
      <msgroup position='-1'>  <!-- extra shift to move to the right of the "." -->
        <mn> 9</mn>
        <msline length="3"/>
        <mn> 1</mn>
      </msgroup>
    </msgroup>
  </mlongdiv>
</math>

The above should produce the following result:

However, this is what InDesign actually renders:

How would I go about troubleshooting this in InDesign?
